# Compactness of three dimensional torus

Tags: general-topology

The three dimensional torus  (the periodic domain in Navier-Stokes equations $\mathbb{T}^3=(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^3$) is compact.  Can anyone here give us a detailed proof.

Comment: Well $\mathbb{T}$ is compact by Heine-Borel, and the finite cartesian product of compact spaces is still compact...

Comment: Technically not a duplicate, but all of the comments and answers there are relevant.

Answer (score 4):

It's a quotient space of $[0,1]^3$, or homeomorphic to $S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1$.